# 80070010 error code

Tags: 8.1, store, games, nokia-lumia-730

I am trying to install a game . When I click on install I am getting an error

> There has been a problem completing your request.Try again later.
>   This error code may be helpful:80070010.

What this error means and how would I download that game?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/error-code-80070010/2c3d8046-e4e6-4a91-b006-38ff50e53d0e

Comment: Yes! I have done that .Even though same problem

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/error-code-80070010/5dcc1ceb-142b-45e4-80c9-1d31d95ecafd

Answer (score 1):

This error code is associated with unavailability of service. This is probably due to an error with the Microsoft Store on the mobile device itself.

Restart the phone. Sync your Microsoft account. Check time and date of your mobile is it correct? Also check regions and regional formats. Also, make sure your default applications installation location is the phone memory, as some apps do not perform well, or even install onto the SD card.